# Access attribute value xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to access the longitude value (-1.914) from this xml snippet where itemfileUID = 2000044 using an xpath query in vba [via Set latitudes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//ViewCoordinates[itemFileUID = '2000044']/ViewCoordinatePair[@name = 'latitude']/@value").] Can anyone help?

I have searched and searched but not found a way to find an attribute value based upon the contents of an element in the same node.

Thanks
Tom

```
<schema>
    <view>
        <ViewCoordinatesList>
            <ViewCoordinates>
                <itemFileUID>2000044</ItemFileUID>
                <ViewCoordinatePair name="longitude" value="-1.91496237"/>
                <ViewCoordinatePair name="latitude" value="53.70811065"/>
                <ViewCoordinatePair name="height" value="136.06"/>
                <ViewCoordinatePair name="yaw" value="168.083809"/>
            </ViewCoordinates>
        </ViewCoordinatesList>
    </view>
</schema>
```

Comment: Note that you are asking `latitude`, but mentioning `-1.914` which is `longitude` in your sample.

Comment: @alecxe apologies - updated now to longitude

Comment: vba snipped added above linked to @alecxe response

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//itemFileUID[. = '2000044']/following-sibling::ViewCoordinatePair[@name = 'longitude']/@value
```

Or, checking the parent:

```
//ViewCoordinates[itemFileUID = '2000044']/ViewCoordinatePair[@name = 'longitude']/@value
```

Comment: thanks for this - I am trying to msgbox this value but failing?

Comment: @TomH okay, failing how? Where are you running this in? Thanks.

Comment: @alexce - vba - this returns a IXMLDOMSelection and I don't know how to access the string... this isn't my field as you can guess...

Comment: @TomH not familiar with xml parsing with VBA unfortnately, but I suspect you should match the nodes first omitting the `/@value` part at the end. Then, when you have a node, get the value of `value` attribute/property.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
Set latitude = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/schema/View/ViewCoordinatesList/ViewCoordinates[ItemFileUID = '2000044']/ViewCoordinatePair[@name = 'longitude']")
MsgBox latitude(0).getAttribute("value")
```

Thanks for people's help